# Intellij auto import for inner classes

Tags: java, import, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij 10.5 and I'd like to be able to use the automatic generation of import lines to allow for inner classes, but I don't see it as a settings preference. Is this possible?

Example's worth a thousand words:

```
public class Foo {
  public static class Bar {
  }
}
```

I'm writing some code that needs to use an instance of Bar:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
```

Intellij correctly brings up Bar as one of the suggestions for importing, but when I select it, it does the following:

```
import package.Foo;

Foo.Bar bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

whereas what I'd like is:

```
import package.Foo.Bar;

Bar bar = new Bar();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check the checkbox under `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports > Insert imports for inner classes`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I had turned it on long ago, but intellij has this bug where it keeps importing when i try to tab complete an inner enum constant *in the same source file* and now i can turn it off.  yay!